# Blazor: Reloading of strings works when user reached bottom at page; but if images are involved it stops working

Tags: blazor

I created this script in my host.cshtml file:

```
<script>
    function isScrollAtBottom(container) {
        return container.scrollHeight - container.scrollTop === container.clientHeight;
    }
</script>
```

Then I have some very simply frontend logic to load some pictures from the resources folder:

```
<div @ref="scrollContainer" @onscroll="HandleScroll" style="overflow:scroll; height: 100vh;">

    @foreach (var item in FC)
    {
        <FunnyLayout ImageId="@item.ImageId" ImageTitle="@item.ImageTitle" />
        <div class="spacer"></div>
    }

    @foreach (var item in items)
    {
        <p>@item</p>
    }

</div>




<style>
    .spacer{
        height: 40px;
    }
</style>


@code {
    private List<string> items = new List<string>
    {
        "Item 1", "Item 2", "Item 3"
    };

    private List<FunnyContent> FC = new List<FunnyContent>
    {
        new FunnyContent{ImageId = "gif", ImageTitle = "il neggtt"},
        new FunnyContent{ImageId = "1", ImageTitle = "was geht"},
        new FunnyContent{ImageId = "2", ImageTitle = "ma boy"},
    };

    private ElementReference scrollContainer;

    [Inject]
    private IJSRuntime JSRuntime { get; set; }

    protected override async Task OnInitializedAsync()
    {

    }

    private async Task HandleScroll()
    {
        var isAtBottom = await JSRuntime.InvokeAsync<bool>("isScrollAtBottom", scrollContainer);
        if (isAtBottom)
        {
            LoadMoreContent();
        }
    }

    private void LoadMoreContent()
    {

        items.Add("New Item");
        items.Add("Another New Item");

        var x = new FunnyContent { ImageId = "1", ImageTitle = "himom0" };
       // FC.Add(x);
       // FC.Add(x);
       // FC.Add(x);
    }

    private class FunnyContent
    {
        public string ImageId { get; set; }
        public string ImageTitle { get; set; }
    }
```

Now, what happens when I scroll down, "new item" and "another new item" are added to my list and I can continue scrolling. Once I scrolled through those two, another two items are added.
This happens indefinately.
So far, so good,.

But notice how I commented out to add the "funny content" ? This is a component, rendering pictures.
But as soon as I comment it in, it will reload exactly ONCE and then the boolto check wether we hit the end or not is always false,

Why does it work with the texts, but as not with the images?
I am of great bamboozel!

Best,

J

Comment: Are you trying to virtualize the list? Simple use the in-built virtualize component. In my experience, use JS with Blazor only if you must (i.e. tracking keypress events, isolated JS libraries etc).

Answer (score 0):

Seems the problem mostly occurs when you render both the lists at the same time.

[Bad Case Snippet](https://blazorfiddle.com/s/vux60obu)

I don't think the js code you have is good for this sort of behaviour. The Bad case snippet above shows another buggy behaviour as it renders the FC list indefinitely because the second list is being rendered below it therefore it never scrolls up when new items are added.

However, I noticed that at one point the `container.clientHeight` would be 593 while the calculation `container.scrollHeight - container.scrollTop` would go down to a maximum of 594 therefore, it never ran that function again. This seems to be the case you were describing.

**It works** when you remove the other list from the container `div`. But, I'd recommend finding a different way or improving the js code.

[Good Case Snippet](https://blazorfiddle.com/s/btcxx6s6)